# Illegal start of expression with two dimensional arrays?

Tags: java

Please help! For AP Comp Sci, I was suppose to copy a program and compile it, then modify it to do something else. However, as I copy this from the book, for some reason I got 3 errors on this in lines 14(public void set...), 38(private stat... ROWS), and 39 (private stat... COLUMNS). What am I doing wrong?

```
    public class TicTacToe
    {
        public TicTacToe()
        {
        board = new String[ROWS][COLUMNS];
        for(int i = 0; i < ROWS; i++)
        {
            for(int j = 0; j <COLUMNS; j++)
            {
                board[i][j] = " ";
            }
        }

        public void set(int i, int j, String player)
        {
            if (board[i][j].equals(" "))
            {
                board[i][j] = player;
            }
        }

        public String toString()
        {
            String r = "";
            for(int i = 0; i < ROWS; i++)
            {
                r = r + "|"
                for(int j = 0; j < COLUMNS; j++)
                {
                    r = r+ board[i][j];
                }
                r = r + "|\n"
            }
            return r;
        }

        private String[][] board;
        private static final int ROWS = 3;
        private static final int COLUMNS = 3;
    }
}
```

Comment: Please make sure that every `{` you open is closed with `}`. Respecting identation will help you with that in future programs.

Comment: java error reporting is usually pretty good, you should actually post the errors and not just what lines they are on

Answer (score 1):

You are missing a "}" at the end of the first for loop.

If you used an IDE like Eclipse, it would show you things like that.

Answer (score 1):

You were also missing some `;`s to end lines

```
public class TicTacToe
{
    private final String[][] board;
    private static final int ROWS = 3;
    private static final int COLUMNS = 3;

    public TicTacToe()
    {
        board = new String[ROWS][COLUMNS];
        for (int i = 0; i < ROWS; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < COLUMNS; j++)
            {
                board[i][j] = " ";
            }
        }
    }

    public void set(final int i, final int j, final String player)
    {
        if (board[i][j].equals(" "))
        {
            board[i][j] = player;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public String toString()
    {
        String r = "";
        for (int i = 0; i < ROWS; i++)
        {
            r = r + "|";
            for (int j = 0; j < COLUMNS; j++)
            {
                r = r + board[i][j];
            }
            r = r + "|\n";
        }
        return r;
    }
}
```

Don't forget to override `hashCode()`, too.